# How validate <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a two model

```
Gallery

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessible :name, :description, :pictures_attributes

    validates_presence_of :pictures
end

Picture

    class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :gallery

      has_attached_file :image,
        :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
        :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"
    end
```

And form

```
    <%= form_for @gallery, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
    .........
     <div class="controls">
          <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
        </div>
    .........
    <% end %>
```

Controller

```
    def create
        @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @gallery.save

            if params[:images]         
              params[:images].each { |image|
                @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
              }
            end

            format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
private

  def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:description,
                                    :name,
                                    :pictures
                                   )
  end
```

If I want to validate has_many pictures image blank?, I got every time a error that Pictures is blank, even I selected images.

How I validate has_many association with multiple image field?

Params

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MCkZFvsYvRndlfaqwXiw5MfhSHGoesawEAPFWzn0Ulw=", "gallery"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>""}, "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb7ad9cb7d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/r4/jqx7vz8d48z2ky3ndpyzv9vc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150926-38180-1xrchqg>, @original_filename="yamaha-blaster-BOARD-HEROa.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"yamaha-blaster-BOARD-HEROa.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "commit"=>"Create Gallery"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Can you show your gallery controller?

Comment: Can you check the server log for unpermitted parameter warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your use of [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) - your model reference is to `pictures` whilst you're referring to `images` in your code.

Here's how you should do it:

```
#app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery
   validates :image, presence: true

   has_attached_file :image,
        :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
        :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"
end

#app/models/gallery.rb
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pictures
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
end
```

You're getting confused about the `image` object and the `Picture` model. IE you need to pass the `images` to the `Picture` model through your `Gallery` model:

```
#app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @gallery = Gallery.new
      @gallery.pictures.build
   end

   def create
      @gallery = Gallery.new gallery_params
      @gallery.save
   end

   private

   def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:description, :name, pictures_attributes: [:images])
   end
end
```

This means you're going to have to use `f.fields_for`, which can be tricky.

Here's how to do it:

```
#app/views/galleries/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @gallery do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture| %>
      <%= picture.file_field type: :file, multiple: true %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should work for you. The *multiple* aspect of the upload, I am not sure about.

Comment: I starting get `Unknown key: allow_blank`

Comment: Sorry my bad, shouldn't have been there

Comment: I delete it but get `undefined method `field_for' for #<ActionView::Helpers`

Comment: it should be fields_for replace to this in your new.html.erb<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture| %> in

Comment: Sorry, again, another typo

Comment: validates :image, presence: true does not work, I can save form with out files.

Comment: Can you save it with files? You can fix the validation later